# Showing sites in Site Collection using a CQWP

Tags: content-query-web-part

Does anyone know the best way to display a listing of sites within a Site Collection using a Content Query Web Part?

I know that you can query content types but what would be the best way to show sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SiteDirectory for SharePoint 2010 from CodePlex gives you a site listings list. You can download the code from CodePlex http://spsitedirectory2010.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've been looking at very closely lately is configuring the search results web part to execute a set query filtering down to the STS_Site and STS_Web objects.  This would automatically filter out the sites the user doesn't have access to and wouldn't need to be maintained.  The XSLT used to create the display is completely customizable so a meaningful display can be created and re-used.

Comment: Great idea Mike! I might to give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

a good route for me was using the table of contents web part.  best thing about it is it inherits target audiencing.  if needed, hide any subsites in site settings - navigation.